# Populate a collection for a form in a before_filter in ActiveAdmin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin

I am trying to populate a collection (@displayable_collection) to select from in my form
(this is a simplified version of what will eventually go into @displayable_collection

Here is my code...  but it isn't working .....  what am I doing wrong?

```
controller do
  before_filter :populate_collection, :only => [:new, :edit]

  private
  def populate_collection
    @displayable_collection = ArtItem.all.map{ |item| [item.to_s, "#{item.class}_#{item.id}"]}
  end
end

form do |f|
  f.inputs 'Details' do
    f.input :project
    f.input :name
  end

  f.inputs 'Display Items' do
    f.has_many :display_items do |item|
      item.input :displayable_combined_fields, :collection => @displayable_collection
      item.input :location, :input_html => {:selected => location.id}
      item.input :height
      item.input :width
      item.input :depth
    end
  end
  f.actions
end
```

Comment: action should be `edit` instead of `update`, also you can do that query in `collection` instead of in a `before_filter`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the Answer is that you reference the instance variable as a helper method.  I know it sounds weird, but it works.

Documented here:  https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/issues/2298

```
controller do
  before_filter :populate_collection, :only => [:new, :edit]

  private
  def populate_collection
    @displayable_collection = ArtItem.all.map{ |item| [item.to_s, "#{item.class}_#{item.id}"]}
  end
end

form do |f|
  f.inputs 'Details' do
    f.input :project
    f.input :name
  end

  f.inputs 'Display Items' do
    f.has_many :display_items do |item|
      item.input :displayable_combined_fields, :collection => displayable_collection
      item.input :location, :input_html => {:selected => location.id}
      item.input :height
      item.input :width
      item.input :depth
    end
  end
  f.actions
end
```